# How can I change the sound keeping the arpeggio in cubase?

Tags: midi, cubase

I've made an instrument track with the Zebra2 synth playing an arpeggio. Now I want my Analogue 303 to play the pattern via MIDI. It has worked before but I don't know how I did it. How can it be done? I can create a new track with the 303 via MIDI but then if I move the score MIDI part to the track then it doesn't play the arpeggio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Zebra's own built-in arpeggiator.

It would be more portable if you used the Cubase's Arpeggiator - Arpache - find it from the Inspector > Midi Sends
You'll have to repatch it to whichever synth you want it to affect, but you don't actually need to keep repatching the 'driver' track each time.

You would, of course, first have to recreate the Zebra arpeggio pattern - whether you can do that in 'Classic' or 'Sequencer' mode would depend on the complexity [If you only have Arpache 5, it doesn't have Sequencer mode, I'm afraid, only the SX version does.]

[image]

Comment: I use Cubase 5. Thank you for the answer. But I have nothing interesting in my MIDI send..and nothing else works either. I used to be able tojust pay the sequence on another instrument using the pattern created with the Zebra. Now I can't even use regular MIDI inserts - they make no sound.

Comment: Sorry, it's been too long since I used v5 [I'm on v8 now] - but there has been an arpeggiator of some sort for a long long time

Comment: It was possible but only if I change the MIDI channel to nr 1 for my MIDI instrument. (Cyclone Analgue 303). It sounds good now.